# Why some of ZeroMQ patterns are called "pirate"

Tags: zeromq

Quote from ZeroMQ guide

> However, with a little extra work, this humble pattern becomes a good basis for real
>   work across a distributed network, and we get a set of reliable request-reply (RRR)
>   patterns that I like to call the Pirate patterns (you’ll eventually get the joke, I hope).

Unfortunately I did not get the joke. Can someone explain this, please?

Comment: Pop culture pirates say "Arr". RRR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pirates are known to say "arrrrrrrr" which is similar sounding to the acronym RRR if you said it out loud . bad joke :)